# c++ initialize a struct type with array in it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, visual-c++-6

i.m using vc6, i made a struct like this:

```
struct FileInfo
{
    char   filename[200] = {0};
    char   ext[20] = {0};
    int    f_size=0;
    int    offset=0;
    char*  pData=0;
};
```

but I got a `error C2059: syntax error : '{'` error, 
and i dont know how to initialize arrays inside correctly.

Comment: This requires C++11 support. Have you compiled with that switched on?

Comment: @juanchopanza i'm using vc6

Comment: Then I doubt you have any C++11 support.

Comment: @juanchopanza  juanchopanza is your name?? it seems like a chinese pronunciation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialize the members when you create an instance of this structure. In C++ this is done in the constructor while in C it's done like:

```
struct FileInfo my_file_info = { { 0 }, { 0 }, 0, 0, 0 };
```

The C way can of course be used in C++ too, if you don't want to add a constructor (for example if the structure is shared between a C and a C++ program).